# Replace rtf file contents by text using AltChunk in word Document through openxml creating a space

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to replace rtf file contents by a textToReplaceByRTFContent in main Word Document(destination). However the content from rtf file is inserted in destination file. But there is a space created in destination file. Left indentation becomes 0.56 for the contents that are inserted from rtf file.
I want to get rid of the spaces(left indentation should be 0)

I have copied the rtf file and CriteriaTest.docx file in the below link.
I need to replace "CRITERIA-1" text in CriteriaTest.docx by the Test.rtf contents.
The below code works well, with indentation issue. Please help me to get rid of this.

[Input Files Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CGjDUuoCynKZHwzr_lMAfgfSgzPY4qqN?usp=sharing)

Please find the expected and actual result screenshot over this link
[ActualvsExpected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i1sT.png)

```
public class RTFInserter
{

    public static void InsertRTF(string rtfFilePath, string destinationFileName, string textToReplaceByRTFContent)
    {

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFileName, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            var holders = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>()
             .Where((x) => x.Text == textToReplaceByRTFContent);
            if(holders != null && holders.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach(var textPlaceHolder in holders)
                {
                    if (textPlaceHolder != null)
                    {
                        var parent = textPlaceHolder.Parent;

                        if (!(parent is Run))  // Parent should be a run element.
                        {

                            // Console.Out.WriteLine("Parent is not run");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

                            // MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart;
                            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                                  AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Rtf, altChunkId);


                            // Read RTF document conte
                            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(rtfFilePath))
                            {
                                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                                memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
                                fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

                                memStream.Position = 0;
                                chunk.FeedData(memStream);
                            }


                            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;


                            textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter(altChunk, textPlaceHolder);

                            // Remove text place holder.
                            textPlaceHolder.Remove();
                            wordDoc.Save();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Text textPlaceHolder = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>()
            // .Where((x) => x.Text == textToReplaceByRTFContent).FirstOrDefault();


        }
    }
}
```